# What is the best way to set up a table for a puzzle like this

Tags: puzzle

I need to rearrange this to form a logical sequence. One way is to just to trial and error, however since there are 5*4*3 ways this can rearrange, that is not efficient. Is there a way to number the elements so I can see a pattern clearly?

Comment: Why did you vandalize your question by removing the actual puzzle?

Comment: OP: I've restored the original puzzle.  If there's a valid reason for removing it (copyright issues? puzzle is in error?), please explain.

Comment: yes i should have explained, I don't think i am allowed to have this photo up.

Answer (score 2):

**Basic approach.**  Conceding that I haven't looked too closely at this, I would proceed as follows:

There are five shapes: circle, cross, diamond, heart, and slashed ring (the "don't" symbol).  There are four textures: graph paper, polka-dotted, slashed, solid.  *Individually*, for each of these properties—shape and texture—find the pattern followed by the figures, and then that will help you put these five triplets in a sequence so that the $15$ consecutive figures obey both patterns *simultaneously*.

For instance, for shape, a heart is always followed by what?  Which is always followed by what?  For texture, graph paper is always followed by what?  And so on.

Comment: thanks for that. The aim is to solve this is under 75 seconds.

Comment: @anna_xox: I would say that this approach permits one to solve the puzzle in under $75$ seconds.  However, I concede that you have to be pretty efficient about it: You can't spend too long thinking about the approach, and you might have to combine the steps into one process.